# What is the Euler characteristic of the hyperboloid of one sheet

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

I would like to know what's the Euler characteristic of the hyperboloid of one sheet. I know that $2-2g$ is the Euler characteristic where g is the number of "holes". Using this fact, Euler characteristic of the hyperboloid is -2. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The "fact" you mention is not stated in a rigorous way; there is no definition of 'hole'. (I really dislike this phrasing because of confusions like this.) The precise statement is that if $\Sigma_g$ is the [compact surface without boundary of genus $g$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Orientable_surface), then $\chi(\Sigma_g) = 2-2g$.

The hyperboloid of one sheet is not compact, so it does not fit into this statement. It deformation retracts onto a circle, and the Euler characteristic is a homotopy invariant, so $\chi(H) = \chi(S^1) = 0$.

Comment: I wonder how can i understand this stuff. What book should i read to understand this rigorously ?  Any recommendation ?

Comment: @KelvinLois I suggest reading a book that includes the classification of surfaces and a definition of Homology. I don't know an example off the top of my head, but here are some things that might be good, in increasing order of difficulty: Kinsey, "Topology of surfaces"; Lee, "Topological manifolds"; Stillwell, "Classical topology and combinatorial group theory". The first book has an incorrect definition of a topology but it's otherwise good.

Comment: I have read Lee’s Topological Manifold at some extend but have not done read the whole chapters needed to complete the proof of the classification theorem. I’ll consider Stillwell’s though. It’s looks interesting. Thanks Mike.